# Exclude quickfix buffer from `:bnext` `:bprevious`

Tags: vim

The quickfix buffer (opened with `:cope` after a `:make` for instance) is included in the `:bnext` `:bprevious` navigation which I use very frequently (having mapped it to the arrow keys). I never want to navigate to the quickfix buffer that way however. Is there a good way to exclude it?

Comment: I guess you'll have to define a mapping on top of `:bn` and `:bprev`, and to check whether the new buffer is the quickfix buffer (and apply the command once again in that case)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
augroup qf
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType qf set nobuflisted
augroup END
```

See `:help 'buflisted'`.